# How to iterate by more than first accepted element in ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, parsing, extract, elementtree

What should I use to iterate more than one element? The code extracts only the first one that is fulfilled, in this case - 'PROCESSING_LEVEL" and then probably ends its function. When I swap these elements, the situation is reversed.
I'm trying to make an app to extract and parse the metadata from XML.

```
tree = ET.parse(filepath)
root: Element = tree.getroot()

for Processing_level in root.iter('PROCESSING_LEVEL' or 'processingLevel'):
    print(f'Processing level: {Processing_level.text}') #console
    text.insert('1.0', Processing_level.text + '\n') #gui
    text2.insert('1.0', Processing_level.text + '\n') #gui`
```

I tried to use other libraries, but I feel like ET is the proper one. I didn't find other method to make it clear to import.xml attributes from tags in different files.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4gCA.png)

Comment: Does your XML contain both `PROCESSING_LEVEL` and `processingLevel` elements? Having `or` in `iter()` looks really strange.

Comment: Please share your input xml and the expected output

Comment: No, maybe I wasn't clear enough. The thing is to extract these arguments 'PROCESSING_LEVEL' or 'processingLevel' from different files, depending on where the argument occurs (while the first one appear in the file it is imported, if it's not the loop searches for the next one). I attached image to make it clear.

Comment: In Python, `'PROCESSING_LEVEL' or 'processingLevel'` evaluates to `'PROCESSING_LEVEL'`, and `'processingLevel' or 'PROCESSING_LEVEL'` evaluates to `'processingLevel'`. Using a library does not change the semantics of Python expressions; the argument is evaluated before the library function is called. The (optional) argument to the `.iter` node method in `ElementTree` is a string naming a (single) tag. So it's doing what it said it would do.

Answer (score 0):

`root.iter()` function iterates more than one element. If you need only specific elements, you can add an if condition in python to a list.

`b.xml` :- sample xml file

```
<root>
  <PROCESSING_LEVEL>LH</PROCESSING_LEVEL>
  <test2>34</test2>
  <processingLevel>2A</processingLevel>
  <test>23</test>
</root>
```

`main.py` :

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("b.xml")
root: ET.Element = tree.getroot()


for Processing_level in root.iter():
  if(Processing_level.tag in ['PROCESSING_LEVEL','processingLevel']):
    print(f'Processing level: {Processing_level.text}') #console
```

`output` :

```
Processing level: LH
Processing level: 2A
```